# How do I add a title and close button to the top of a menu (above the 1st item in a button menu when clicked in material-ui?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have an icon button menu that contains a checkbox list of menuitems.  I want to add a title to the menu when the user clicks on the icon and opens the dropdown, at the top of the dropdown with a close button.

What I currently do is use the 1st menuitem and disable it, override the style and display a title.  I really hate this, because it's not the way it should be done.  Now I want to add a close button to the right side of the tite, but since the menuitem is disabled, I can't do it.

Here's my code:

```
    <DropdownButtonMenu
        id="customized-menu"
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        keepMounted
        PaperProps={{
            style: {
                maxHeight: 225,
            },
        }}
        open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
        onClose={handleClose}
    >
        <TitleMenuItem disabled={true} className='classes.title'>
            <Typography variant="subtitle1" >
                {menuTitle}
            </Typography>
            //**NEED TO ADD A CLOSE BUTTON HERE AND NOT BE DISABLED
        </TitleMenuItem>
        {formColumns.map(colobj => (
            <CheckboxMenuItem
                key={`ckb-${colobj.name}`}
                className={classes.SearchMenuItem}
                selected={false}
                onClick={handleClose} >
                <Checkbox
                    checked={GetChecked(colobj)}
                    onChange={handleCheckboxClick} //Need to add 1,2 or 3 as parameter to this onChange event
                    className={classes.searchColumnCheckbox}
                    value={`${colobj.name}`} />
                    {colobj.label}
            </CheckboxMenuItem>
        ))}
    </DropdownButtonMenu>
```

I created a TitleMenuItem by subclassing the MenuItem as below:

```
const TitleMenuItem = styled(MuiMenuItem)({
    disabled: props => props.opacity ? '1.0' : '1.0',
    color: props => props.color ? '#0047ab' : '#0047ab',
    margin: '0px',
    padding: '0px',
    paddingLeft: '8px',
});
```

And did similar with the DropDownButtonMenu and CheckboxMenuItem:

```
const DropdownButtonMenu = withStyles({
    paper: {
        border: "1px solid #d3d4d5",
        muiListPadding: {
            marginTop: '0px',
            paddingTop: '0px',

    }
    },
})(props => (
    <Menu
        elevation={0}
        getContentAnchorEl={null}
        anchorOrigin={{
            vertical: "bottom",
            horizontal: "center"
        }}
        transformOrigin={{
            vertical: "top",
            horizontal: "center"
        }}
        {...props}
    />
));

const CheckboxMenuItem = withStyles(theme => ({
    root: {
        "&:focus": {
            backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
            color: theme.palette.common.white,
            "& .MuiListItemIcon-root, & .MuiListItemText-primary": {
                color: theme.palette.common.white
            }
        },
        paddingTop: "2px",
        paddingBottom: "2px",
        paddingRight: "0px",
        paddingLeft: "4px",
        margin: "2px",
        fontSize: "0.8rem",
        lineHeight: "1",
    }
}))(MenuItem);
```

Am I going about this completely wrong?  All I want is a title on a dropdown menulist w/a close button.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: May you provide https://codesandbox.io/ sample?

Comment: Yes, @ArturRubens is right. Could you create codesendbox and we will help you.

Comment: Thanks guys for commenting.  I got a good answer from Ryan below.  I suspected I shouldn't be using MenuItem, but didn't know how to replace the functionality.  Ryan hit it spot on.  And yes, I should show stuff in code sandbox.  I'm still trying to figure out how to add libraries to it to get it to the point I can put my code in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To keep a valid structure, you want your title/button element to render an `<li>` element (since `Menu` renders it within a `<ul>` element). `MenuItem` [renders an `<li>`](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.11.0/packages/material-ui/src/MenuItem/MenuItem.js#L38), but it also does some things you don't want -- the main one being that it renders the entire `<li>` [as a button](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.11.0/packages/material-ui/src/MenuItem/MenuItem.js#L54) using the `button` prop of `ListItem`.

To avoid having the entire `<li>` treated like a button, I would use `ListItem` as your starting point (which provides a reasonable starting point for styling).

My other suggestion is a bit of a hack that is dependent on implementation details that could change in the future. When `Menu` opens it will try to put focus on the first non-disabled menu item (there are ways of modifying this functionality, but for the most part this is desirable). It determines whether a menu item is disabled by [looking for a `disabled` prop](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.11.0/packages/material-ui/src/MenuList/MenuList.js#L234) on the immediate children of the `Menu`. So my suggestion is to give your title element the `disabled` prop, but to have your custom `ListItem` ignore that prop.

This would look something like this:

```
const IgnoreDisabledListItem = React.forwardRef(function IgnoreDisabledListItem(
  { disabled, ...other },
  ref
) {
  return <ListItem {...other} ref={ref} />;
});
```

and then use it later like the following:

```
        <IgnoreDisabledListItem disabled>
          My Title{" "}
          <IconButton onClick={handleClose}>
            <CloseIcon />
          </IconButton>
        </IgnoreDisabledListItem>
```

Specifying the `disabled` prop in the JSX will prevent `Menu` from giving focus to this item, but `IgnoreDisabledListItem` prevents that `disabled` prop from having any other effects.

Here is a full working example:

```
import React from "react";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Menu from "@material-ui/core/Menu";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import ListItem from "@material-ui/core/ListItem";
import CloseIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Close";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";

const IgnoreDisabledListItem = React.forwardRef(function IgnoreDisabledListItem(
  { disabled, ...other },
  ref
) {
  return <ListItem {...other} ref={ref} />;
});
export default function SimpleMenu() {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);

  const handleClick = event => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button
        aria-controls="simple-menu"
        aria-haspopup="true"
        onClick={handleClick}
      >
        Open Menu
      </Button>
      <Menu
        id="simple-menu"
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        keepMounted
        open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
        onClose={handleClose}
      >
        <IgnoreDisabledListItem disabled>
          My Title{" "}
          <IconButton onClick={handleClose}>
            <CloseIcon />
          </IconButton>
        </IgnoreDisabledListItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>My account</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Logout</MenuItem>
      </Menu>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Title and button in first menu item]

Comment: Wow Brian.  That worked perfectly.  Just had to restyle the title a bit.  I truly appreciate it!  Wish I knew react better than I do.  Just want to get away from M$ stuff.

Comment: Where does one go or read to learn more about things like React.forwardRef?  I'd never even heard of it before.  Yikes. What else don't I have a clue about.  It's scary.

Comment: @AndrewH You can find some info in the react docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html#forwarding-refs-to-dom-components and https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactforwardref.

Comment: Thanks Ryan. Didn't know that page even existed.  Has some handy tools in it.